# Arduino Uno - What can I make with just the base board

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

So I just bought my first Arduino (an Uno r3), and dove right in.

All I have currently is the base board (I didn't want to invest too heavily and then realize arduinos weren't for me), so I made a quick script that translates input letters to morse via the LED on the top.

Now that I'm done with that, I figured I'd come here to ask: do you guys have any random ideas for things I can make with JUST the uno? I understand that I should probably just start buying kits and shields, but I'm just curious as to what I can make with the most minimal of items. I consider it a test :)

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: You can do anything that only involves talking on the serial connection and blinking the LED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

Your question is very broad. But the Arduino essentially needs controlling gadgteers to make things easy ( and funny ).

However if you know a bit of electronics, then you may be able to use the IN/OUT analog ports and build other interfaces to control, for example the lights of your home, or even better. You can measure and control priate things should be linked. Increasing the power of your home.

If you have interest in cars, then you can perform to connect the on-board computer of your car to the Arduino, like [this](http://arduinodev.com/connect-arduino-to-a-car-through-obd-ii-port/).

Well, there are numerous ideas, none of these I'm saying is new and there are even libraries ready to be used in these segments mentioned above.

Regards,
Andrew Paes

Comment: Thank you for your multiple examples! I realize my question is extremely broad, but I think you did a good job of answering it. I thought about making a lightswitch controller but that would require some other components, correct? Unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: At least 1 push button costing you $2,00. Would better Would better buy a LCD Multi Touch display costing around $9,00 giving you the chance to have any buttons as you want.